# Cron job doesn't run 'runner' task that uses Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, sidekiq, whenever

I generated a Cront Job using the Whenever gem

```
every 15.minutes do
    command "date >> ~/cron.txt"
    runner "Location.update_days"
end
```

By typing `crontab -l` in the command line I get:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'date >> ~/cron.txt'

0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /opt/www/my_app && bin/rails runner -e production '\''Location.update_days'\'''
```

Apparently the `command` tasks work just fine and I do get the `date` printed to `cron.txt` every 15 minutes but the `runner` task doesn't run.

The `Location.update_days` calls a Sidekiq worker to perform a task and it works when run from the `rails console` but not when it is called by cron.

```
def self.update_days
   new_day = self.new_day

   self.where( current_location: true,
            self.season => new_day[:timezone]
          ).find_each do |location|
            day = location.days.create new_day
            SidekiqWorker.perform_async day.id
          end
end
```

Do you have any idea what might be wrong or how can I debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know that you said it ran from the console fine, but did you try running the bash script that the cron job runs to see if there were obvious errors? It's possible that the cron job fails before the Ruby class is even loaded.

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /opt/www/my_app && bin/rails runner -e production '\''Location.update_days'\'''
```

Comment: Yes, and it prompt me to the newline showing an `>` at the biginning of the line just like it would in the `rails console`, but if I type something like Location.first and hit enter just prompts me to another new line without showing any result

Comment: Why do you think that is?

Comment: Apparently the BackSlashes caused the problem. without them it works in the console but it is kind of strange since they were added by Whenever

Comment: `$ bin/rails runner -e production 'Location.update_days'`  <= this works in the console